# Python sequence cluster exercise

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, dynamic-programming

I am working through an exercise in my textbook and am implementing the code in Python to practice dynamic programming. I feel like I am right on the edge of figuring it out, but after many hours, I come here for help.

Basically my code is going through a list of values `x`, and given a `k`, break that list into `k` clusters based on calculating the minimum sum of squared errors (SSE) for a particular cluster.

The code creates a table, calculating the SSE for 1 cluster, 2 clusters, ..., k clusters, if we were to put the cluster parentheses around all variations of values within `list[0:1]`, `list[0:2]`, `list[0:3]`, ..., `list[0:n]`, and choosing the minimum SSE for that particular step in the table.

For example: Given `x= [7,6,9,15,18,17,30,28,29]` and `k=3`, we would return clusters `(7,6,9)(15,18,17)(30,28,29)`, which would translate to sum of squared error equal to `(4.666)(4.666)(2)` for each cluster. So our max SSE would be `4.666` for that clustering on that list.

Now when I try it on my second list `x = [52, 101, 103, 101, 6, 5, 7]`, I should get clustering `(52)(101, 103, 101)(6, 5, 7)`, which should give `(0)(2.666)(2)` or a max of `2.666`, but am not getting that. I believe the error lives in the  `def f(s, j_down, t)` for the 2nd return statement, and how I increment `s` and `t`. Hopefully I have not made a silly mistake!

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

```
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

def sum_square(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int,)):
        return 0
    w = 0
    for i in x:
        w += (i - mean(x))**2
    return w

def f(s, j_down, t):
    if not r[s][j_down] and r[s][j_down] != 0:
        return sum_square(x[:t - s])

    return max(r[s][j_down], sum_square(x[:t-s]))

def get_min_f_and_s(j_down, t):
    """ range s from 1 to t-1 and set s to minimize f(s)
    """
    items = [(s, f(s, j_down, t)) for s in range(t)]
    s, min_f = min(items, key=lambda x:x[1])
    return s, min_f

def seq_out(n,k):
    for j in range(k):
        if j == 0:
            for t in range(n):
                r[t][j] = sum_square(x[:t+1])

                c[t][j] = x[:t+1]
        else:
            for t in range(1, n):
                s, min_f = get_min_f_and_s(j - 1, t)
                r[t][j] = min_f
                c[t][j] = [c[s][j - 1]] + x[s+1:t+1]

    print('the max SSE is: {}'.format(r[-1][-1]))
    print('the cluster centers are: {}'.format(c[-1][-1]))

#x = [7,6,9,15,18,17,30,28,29]    
x = [52, 101, 103, 101, 6, 5, 7]
k = 3
n = len(x)

r = [[[] for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]
c = [[[] for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]

print(seq_out(n,k))
print(r)
print(c)
```

Edit: Question layout

Given a sequence `X = [x_1, x_2, ... x_n]` and integer `k > 1`, partition `X` into clusters `C_1,..., C_k` of sizes `n_1, ..., n_k`, so that the sum of squared errors is minimized.

Comment: In [another question you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073517/python-number-line-cluster-exercise), you shared an image of the page with the algorithm you were working from. Could you please do that here as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to trace how you think your code should work, and therefore I cannot tell you what mistake you are making.  Also since you're trying to learn I'll offer you the opportunity to think through how to do it, rather than just code that appeared by magic.

Assuming that you want to have a bottom up approach, one approach is to fill in the following table (which is better done as an array of arrays, but I'll do as a dictionary of dictionaries to make it easier to read):

```
best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters = {
    0: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 0.0}
        },
    1: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 1200.5, 'max_error': 1200.5},
        2: {'start': 1, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 0.0},
        }, 
    2: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 1668.6666666666667, 'max_error': 1668.6666666666667},
        2: {'start': 1, 'error': 2.0, 'max_error': 2.0},
        3: {'start': 2, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 0.0},
        },
    3: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 1852.75, 'max_error': 1852.75},
        2: {'start': 1, 'error': 2.666666666666667, 'max_error': 2.666666666666667},
        3: {'start': 3, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 2.0},
        },
    4: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 7397.2, 'max_error': 7397.2},
        2: {'start': 4, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 1852.75},
        3: {'start': 4, 'error': 0.0, 'max_error': 2.666666666666667},
        },
    5: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 11205.333333333334, 'max_error': 11205.333333333334},
        2: {'start': 4, 'error': 0.5, 'max_error': 1852.75},
        3: {'start': 4, 'error': 0.5, 'max_error': 2.666666666666667},
        },
    6: {
        1: {'start': 0, 'error': 13735.714285714286, 'max_error': 13735.714285714286},
        2: {'start': 4, 'error': 2.0, 'max_error': 1852.75},
        3: {'start': 4, 'error': 2.0, 'max_error': 2.666666666666667},
        },
}
```

Here is how to interpret that table.

The fact that `best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters[6][3]` is `{'start': 4, 'error': 2.0, 'max_error': 2.666666666666667}` means that the optimal division of the numbers from positions 0-6 is to have the third cluster have the numbers at positions 4, 5, 6.  That cluster has a squared error of 2.0, and goes with a max of 2.666666666666667.  Which gives you the cluster `[6, 5, 7]` and to find the rest we go to `best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters[3][2]` (ie best division into 2 clusters ending at position 3) and we similarly find the cluster `[101, 103, 101]`.  And then we're left looking at `best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters[0][1]` (best 1 cluster ending at position 0) which gives us the last cluster of `[52]`.

So figure out how to write code to fill in that table, and then the code to extract the answer from that table, and you'll have a bottom-up dynamic programming solution.

As for filling it in, as an example, to fill in `best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters[3][1]` what I had to do was look at `best_cluster_by_pos_by_clusters[i][0]` for `i=0, 1, 2` to see every division of a previous cluster versus a current one.